# What is the formal definition of series and parallel connections?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

It seems half the time I'm just guessing whether it's series or parallel, is there not a way to definitively determine whether a given connection is series or parallel just by looking at it?

Comment: Could you supply a circuit diagram for which you have this difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

For two elements in *series*, the current that flows through one of them then flows through the other: they share the same current. The sum of their voltage drops equals the supply voltage.

For two elements in *parallel*, the voltage that is across one of them is also across the other: they share the same voltage. The total current is the sum of their individual currents.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know there is SE Electrical Engineering and people there might be more interested in this. Your question cannot be answered for all types of circuits. Some parts may be in series, others may be parallel. If there is only two components such as a power supply and a LED, they are both in series and in parallel. In general parallel means at some point the two electrical elements you are considering are connected on both ends, while in series only one of them connects them together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of looking at the rules.
S: Two resistors are in series if you can trace a line along the wire from one to the other without encountering a junction in the wire.

P: Two resistors are in parallel if you can connect the resistors top to top and bottom to bottom using lines that do not pass through any other resistors.

And here's an algorithm for reducing any circuit that is a combination of series and parallel resistors.

1. Pick a resistor and find any resistors it is in series with using rule (S) above. Group these resistors, calculate their equivalent resistance, and re-draw the circuit so that they appear as just one resistor.
2. Repeat step 1 until there are no more ungrouped resistors in series.
3. Pick a resistor and find any resistors that are in parallel with it using rule (P) above. Group these resistors, calculate their equivalent resistance, and re-draw the circuit.
4. Repeat step 1 until there are no more simplifications to be made. In almost any homework assignment this will end with just a single resistor.

Extra credit: Find a circuit that does not reduce to a single resistor after this algorithm. Hint: it takes at least 5 resistors.